# Why is the movie titled 'Arlington Road'?

Tags: title, arlington-road

The 1999 movie *Arlington Road* is set in Virginia and Washington D.C., with the characters living on the fictional (and titular) road.

Why did the makers of the film choose this name for the road, and for the name of the film?

[image]

Comment: "*The title refers to a street of wealthy people in Bethesda, Maryland, about five miles from Washington, D.C.. Equivalent to Rodeo Drive in Beverly Hills.*" - https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/ArlingtonRoad

Comment: There are about half a dozen roads named "Arlington Road" around DC, both in Maryland and in Virginia, for example in Bethesda, Hopewell, Roanoke, Richmond, Danville, Cape Charles. Is there any reason to assume it is not simply one of those? My parents live in a quarter where every single street is named after a city, none of which are anywhere near.

Comment: In the real town of Reston, Virginia, where the movie is set, there are Brussels Ct, Freetown Dr, Lima Ln, San Jose Dr, Andorra Pl, Panama Rd, Copenhagen Ct, and I am pretty sure Virginia is not near South America, Africa, California, or Europe.

Comment: You say Arlington is not a city in Virginia, but it is a county, part of the metro-DC area, with significant government agencies, including The Pentagon.

Comment: The film [literally takes place on Arlington road](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhUMF.png). Are you asking why the makers chose to call the titular road Arlington Road?

Comment: There are *so many* identical names in the US that it can be confusing sometimes, but it's historical. How many Frederic/Louis/Paris and England/Germany/France related names?

Comment: Yeah I’ve lived in Arlington, VA and even though it may not be an incorporated city we still say "Arlington, Virginia" and write "Arlington, VA" as part of our address as if it’s a city, so around here it kinda is. Certainly people also say "Arlington County" a lot around here but mainly when talking about municipal entities like the Sheriff or board of supervisors. Finally I am reminded of the lyrics by the band Emmet Swimming: "It’s the suburb of the week: Arlington", referring to Arlington VA as a suburb of DC.

Answer (score -3):

The use of "*Arlington*" seems a good shortcut for all the ideas conveyed in the movie. First, the family lives in a nice suburban place, and they're like the average american middle-class family. You can invent a street name that will give the audience something to think about because they already know the name. The whole story "*was heavily inspired by the growing concern in the 1990s regarding the right-wing militia movement, Ruby Ridge, the Waco siege and Oklahoma City bombing*" [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arlington_Road). So, you live in Arlington road, and the danger is right next to you. It's your neighbours, in the same street. The danger, the plot, the explanation, it's all there in Arlington road, no need to go any further. People associate Arlington with pride and death, with honor and fighting an ennemy (often from outside). This time, the ennemy is from the inside.

The mother dies in the line of duty, and even if it's more about military and vererans, some people can be buried in [Arlington National cemetery](https://www.latimes.com/nation/la-121101spann-story.html).

> There are several cities in the US with the name Arlington but none of them are in Virginia or near the DC.

According to the plot, Michael lives with his 9-year-old son Grant in [Reston, Virginia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reston,_Virginia), which is approximately [20 miles](https://www.google.com/search?q=reston+to+arlington+va&oq=reston+to+arli&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqCQgAEAAYExiABDIJCAAQABgTGIAEMgYIARBFGDwyBggCEEUYOTIKCAMQABgTGBYYHtIBCTEyNDU5ajBqN6gCALACAA) from [Arlington, Virginia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arlington_County,_Virginia).

Arlington is home to the Pentagon and Arlington National Cemetery. [Pentagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pentagon) is known for its DOD:

> The United States Department of Defense is an executive branch department of the federal government of the United States charged with coordinating and supervising all agencies and functions of the U.S. government directly related to national security and the United States Armed Forces.

The choice of Arlington when you tell a story about homeland security and terrorism seems also a good reminder of the sense of duty, about the people who fight to protect their country and often die for that.

> “Arlington Road” was an attempt from screenwriter Ehren Kruger and director Mark Pellington to give audiences action and suspense, but also contribute to the developing conversation about domestic terrorism and the insurgent, reactionary right wing of US politics. [Crime Reads](https://crimereads.com/conspiracy-thriller-arlington-road/)

Interesting discussion about the way the title was designed: [Art Of Title](https://www.artofthetitle.com/title/arlington-road/)

Comment: Not even a comment to say why it's considered bad ? This amazes me sometimes...

Comment: I downvoted because you've made a bunch of assertions without any proof to back them up. You've basically just googled the word "Arlington" and copied the top ten answers.

Comment: Good, informative answer to a potentially mediocre question. (I lived on Arctic Street once, which had absolutely nothing to do with the Arctic. Now I live on a street named for a tree that has never grown in this region. irl, street names often have no symbolic meaning, but in a good written work, little things matter.)

Comment: @anongoodnurse: I think it's not *that* bad a question, as there's no reference anywhere about their artistic choice for the name, so it might be interesting to know. When I first watched the movie, this is what it made me think of, the DOD/cemetery related name, as I try and explain in the answer.

Comment: Arlington is more like 10-15 miles from Reston, at least edge to edge as opposed to center to center.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: maps says 17.4 so I rounded ?

Comment: I’m in south Reston right now and it’s 15 miles by car from here to Ballston metro station in Arlington. It would be less as the crow flies and ballston metro is like in the middle of Arlington, not the close edge.